# Looping through dataframe values in columns and using them as a FROM clause using SQL

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I am running BigQuery in Jupyter notebook.

```
query ="""
SELECT 
    table_catalog, 
    table_schema, 
    table_name, 
FROM `Project-A.schema_A`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS
"""
```

The output leads me to the following table:

```
# This is the output of the query
data = {'table_catalog':['project-A', 'project-A', 'project-A', 'project-A','Project-A','Project-A','Project-A'],
        'table_catalog':['schema_A', 'schema_A', 'schema_A', 'schema_A','schema_A','schema_A','schema_A']
        'table_name':['Table_A', 'Table_B', 'Table_B', 'Table_C','Table_C','Table_A','Table_A']}
 
d# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to use Table_A, Table_B and Table_C in my next query in the `FROM` CLAUSE such that it looks like:

```
query =f"""
SELECT
*
FROM Project-A.Schema_A.{I want to edit this dyanmically - either Table_A, Table_B, Table_C}"""
```

I tried the following but have been failing, please help me with this:

```
list_of_tables = list(df['table_name'].unique())

def loop_tables(x):
    for tables in list_of_tables:
        if x == tables
# x = df['table_name']
loop_tables()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def loop_tables():
    list_of_dataframes = []
    for table in list_of_tables:
        print(table)
        dynamic_sql = "select * from project.dataset."
        dynamic_sql += table
        df = client.query(dynamic_sql).to_dataframe()
        list_of_dataframes.append(df)
    return list_of_dataframes
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Follow up question. Now, I am able to access the dataframes by using `list_of_dataframes[0]` up until `list_of_dataframes[13]`. These are based on a `list_of_tables` variable created earlier -->  `['table1', table2',table3',table4'....]`. Is there a quick way to to get list_of_dataframes[0] == 'table1' till list_of_dataframes[13] == 'table14'. Thank you! Still getting the hang of python shortcuts (:

Comment: It would be easier if you elaborate more of your follow up queries.